# How can I get a scrollable sidebar similar to www.youtube.com?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a feature on my page similar to https://www.youtube.com/
Specifically, the tab on the left that includes your playlists, subscriptions, and more.
I'm trying to attempt that but without the collapse feature.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube uses a webkit scrollbar for that section.

Here it is with the same  color schemes. Do note that webkit properties are *not* globally supported.

```css
.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  
  width: 50%;
  
  overflow: auto;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent; 
}
 
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

.content {
  height: 800px;
}

.container-dark {
  background: #212121;
}

.container-dark:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #4A4A4A; 
}

.container-light {
  background: #fff;
}

.container-light:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #cfcfcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-dark">
  <div class="content">some content in dark mode</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-light">
  <div class="content">some content in light mode</div>
</div>
```

YouTube only shows the scrollbar thumb when the container is being hovered, when it isn't being hovered, the scrollbar is transparent.

Comment: As long as you make them scrollable by setting the `overflow` property, yes.

Comment: So, I'll change the .container CSS tags to .col and set the overflow property then?

Comment: If `.col` contains the scrollable content, yes.

Answer (score 7):

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 8px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: #888;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```